# How to use the split function for extracting a number out of a file name?

Tags: python, split

I've got a question.

For a python assignement two .dat files are given:
`steel_samples_S355.dat` and `tests_steelS460.dat`
These files contain 100 numbers of steeltests. My task is to highlight the tests that are below a certain value. For this, I have to split the filename and take the numbers after the `'S'`. So in this case that is `355` and `460`. If the value is below the given average, the number has to be added to a list. All not so difficult, but how do you apply the split function in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but as a tip, if you're going to ask for help for assignments, you need to show that you really tried, not just dump a request list, y'know? Show the code you tried, show the output you got and the output you need. Often, writing the question helps you figure out the answer - and that's a good thing. Save the SO questions for the problems you couldn't solve with a bit of persistence (and also spell check) 

Answer (score 1):

```
average = 33
my_list = []

name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("steel_samples_S355.dat"))[0]
number = int(filename.split('S')[1])

if number < average:
   my_list.append(number)
```